# Проверка на валидность: Имя, фамилия - должно быть заполнено одно из двух

Tags: javascript, reactjs, валидация, react-hook-form

Необходимо выполнить условие: имя, фамилия - должно быть заполнено одно из двух. Как пройти проверку на валидность, чтобы можно после ввода firstName, либо lastName, второй становился необязательным?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
import './App.css';



function App() {
  const {
    register,
    formState:{
      errors,
    },
    handleSubmit,
    isValid,
    reset,

  } = useForm({
    mode:'onBlur',
  });


const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false)



const onChangeFile = (event) => {
  handleFileChange(event);
  fileSize(event);
  };

const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  setIsSuccess(false);

  const allowedTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"];
  if (!allowedTypes.includes(selectedFile?.type)) {
    setIsError(true);
    setErrorMsg("Только изображения JPEG и PNG");
    return;
  }

  setIsError(false);
  setFile(selectedFile);
};

const fileSize = (event) => {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    if (event.target.files[0].size > 2097152) {
      setIsError(true);
      setErrorMsg("Максимум 2МБ" );
      return false;
    }}
}


  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    reset();
  };



  return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="form">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='form-section'> 
          <h1 className='title'>Форма обратной связи</h1>
              
               <input className='firstname-box'
                  placeholder='Введите Имя'
                  {...register('firstname',{ 
                  required: true ,})}
                />

              <div className='error-name_1' style={{height: 40}}>
                {errors?.firstname &&<p>Напишите Имя</p>}
              </div>


                  <input className='lastname-box'
                  placeholder='Введите Фамилию'
                  {...register('lastname', { 
                  required: true,})}
                />
      
            <div className='error-name_2' style={{height: 40}}>
              {errors?.lastname &&<p>Напишите Фамилию</p>}
            </div>


                <input className='email-box'
                placeholder='Введите Email'
                {...register('email',{ 
                required: true,
                })}
              />            

            <div className='error-email' style={{height: 40}}>
              {errors?.email  &&<p>{errors?.email?.message|| 'Обязательное поле'}</p>}
            </div>
            

            <select className='category-box'
                  {...register("category", { required: true })}>
                  <option className='disabled-option' value="" selected disabled>Категория сообщения </option>     
                  <option value="1">Категория 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Категория 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Категория 3</option>
                </select>
            

          <div className='error-category' style={{height: 40}}>
              {errors?.category && <p>Обязательное поле</p>}
            </div>

                <textarea className='text-box'
                placeholder='Введите сообщение'
                name='Введите сообщение' 
                {...register("text", {
                  required: true,
                  minLength: {
                  value: 10,
                  message: 'Минимум 10 символов'
                  }
                  })}
                  >
                  </textarea>


              <div className='error-text' style={{height: 40}}>
                {errors?.text  &&<p>{errors?.text?.message || 'Обязательное поле'}</p>}
            </div>
            
            <input className='photo-box'
              name="file-upload"
              type="file"
              accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
              onChange={onChangeFile} 
            />
            
            <div className="error-photo">
              {isError && <div className="error-text">{errorMsg}</div>}
            </div>
              
              <input type="submit" className="button" />

        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---